# Let Ubuntu 20.04 keep remote desktop on after reboot

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop

Ubuntu 20.04 have the nice feature that you don't need command line to start remote desktop or VNC server (with the "normal" installation choice), just go to Settings-Share.

But each time the machine is rebooted, remote desktop is down and I need to go to setting to re-enable it (means change of monitor input and re-plug of HID devices are needed).

Can it be keeped?